# Prove that $M(t)=N(t)-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

- $N(t)$ - inhomogenous poisson process with intensity $\lambda(t)$
- Number of events $N(t)-N(s)$ in the time interval $(s, t]$ is poisson distributed with parameters $\int_{s}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du$
- Number of events in disjoint time intervals are independent
- $F_t$ is generated by $N(s)$, s$\leqslant$t
- $M(t)=N(t)-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du$

**PROVE THAT:** 
$$E(M(t)\mid F_s)=M(s)\tag{1}$$

I have tried to put $M(t)-M(s)$ in the expected value, but I find it difficult to show that the above is true, which gives me (2):

$$E(M(t)-M(s)\mid F_s)=E(N(t)-N(s))-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du+\int_{s}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du\tag{2}$$

Is not even sure if the above is the correct way to think, but it was an attempt to prove statement (1).

**Someone who can help me?**

Comment: Tried to concoct a non absurd title. Now to the post itself: I am lost, can you prove (2) or not?

Comment: The only thing to be proved is (1). (2) is my attempt to do so. @Did

Comment: I got that, but not *if you know how to prove (2), or not*.

Comment: FYI, you saw fit to modify the title again, with the effect that the current version is ABSURD: if M is a martingale then E(M(t)|F_s)=M(s) for every s<t, *by definition*. Your call, I guess.

Comment: @Did The task is: "Prove that $E(M(t)\mid F_s)=M(s)$ for all s$\leq$t, that is, that $M(t)$ is a Martin gale"

Comment: @Did Sorry, Now I understand ,the task is as you said to prove that, $M(t)=N(t)-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du$

Comment: No, not that either.

Comment: @Did Can you help me? I feel so confused right now.

Comment: Hint: $M(t) = (M(t) - M(s)) + M(s)$

Comment: Also, $\mathbb E[N(t)] = $ ?

Comment: Show that $M(t)=N(t)-\int_{0}^{t}\lambda(u)\,du$ is a martingale.
$M(s)=N(s)-\int_{0}^{s}\lambda(u)\,du$ 
$E(M(t)\mid F_s)$=$E(M(t)-M(s)+M(s)\mid F_s)$=$E(M(t)-M(s)\mid F_s)$+$E(M(s)\mid F_s)$=0+$M(s)$=$M(s)$ , thanks for the help! @Math1000